# how can I change the modelform label and give it a custom name

Tags: django, modelform

I want to create a custom name for on of the labels in my modelform
this is my forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget)
    publish = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget,
        initial=datetime.date.today,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "body",
            "author",
            "image",
            "image_url",
            "video_path",
            "video",
            "publish",
            "tags",
            "status"
         ]
```

I want to change the instead of video I want it to say embed. I checked the documentation but didn't find anything that would help me do that. is it possible without me having to rearrange my model? if so how? thanks

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

> You can specify the **labels**, **help_texts** and **error_messages** attributes of the inner Meta class if you want to further customize a field.

There are examples just below that section of the docs. So, you can do:

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    labels = {
        "video": "Embed"
    }
```

Comment: saved my day, pal! I wanted to mess with db column names xD or at least with model field names xD

Comment: note: if you are translating the label, this should be done in the __init__ method of the form: self.fields['video'].label = _('Embed'). This captures current language at runtime, whereas doing it in Meta makes the translation at startup in default lang (thus will be wrong for users of non-default lang).

Comment: I doubt that's the best way @Sean. You need to use the lazy form of gettext though, i.e.
`from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

Answer (score 27):

Yes, [you can](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#label). Simply use the `label` argument:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    video = forms.FileField(label='embed')
```

or define it inside your `Meta` class:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        labels = {
            "video": "embed"
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class Meta:

    model = Book
    fields = ('title', 'publication_date', 'author', 'price', 'pages','book_type',)
    labels  = {
        'title':'Titulo', 
        'publication_date':'Data de Publicação', 
        'author':'Autor', 
        'price':'Preço', 
        'pages':'Número de Páginas',
        'book_type':'Formato'
        }
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'publication_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'pages': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'book_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to achieve this without editing the form would be to [change the `verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) on the model. For the `video` field on your model you could change the label on the form from "video" to "embed" like so:

```
class Post(models.Model)
    video = models.UrlField(verbose_name="embed")
    # Other fields
```