# non-ASCII characters in column names - a bad idea?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, sqlite, non-ascii-characters

I'm using Django to prepare a small app. One of its features is a form which labels MUST be in Polish, using non-ASCII chars. I'm not sure if the db is going to stay sqlite, postgres or mysql.
Now. I am tempted to use ModelForm to create the form but I don't know about the way of overriding the default labels' texts - i.e. - the respective columns' names. And that compels me to name the columns using non-ASCII letters.

Is it a very bad idea? Could it potentially create many problems? Should I give up ModelForms and turn to Forms instead? Or maybe is there any other solution to combine English (ASCII) column names in the db, ModelForm and Polish labels with non-ASCII chars?

I would be grateful for your advice :)

EDIT:

Now I am thinking about something like that and wonder if non ascii letters in model fields - but not db columns! - could cause any troubles???

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    treść = models.TextField(db_column="body")




 class MyForm(ModelForm):
        Meta:
            model = MyModel
```

Comment: [opinion based] Yes, it is a bad idea. Even MixedCase identifiers are a bad idea (since they effectively force you to quote the identifiers for the rest of your life)

Comment: I agree, it is a bad idea. It might work tough, why not? I don't see how you could be forced into using Polish column names in your database table. A bit of code would have been very welcome. I always program everything in English, including comments and documentation. This makes it much easier to work together with people who don't speak my language.

Comment: e column names don't have to be in Polish but the form labels do... django ModelForm (as far as I get it) takes the Model's fields' names and transform them to labels. I could make Polish fields' names and make different, English column names - I have edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it is a duplicate.
No need to mess with models or db - the answer was here: [how can I change the modelform label and give it a custom name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905060/how-can-i-change-the-modelform-label-and-give-it-a-custom-name)

after all it is possible to change the label names in ModelForm.